# Using ampersand character in href attribute

Tags: html, url

Is it valid html if a link looks like that:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/home.php?a=2&b=5">example</a>
```

Or it should be:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/home.php?a=2&#38;b=5">example</a>
```

Comment: Both are valid, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: No it's not. Why don't you [check it yourself](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options)?

Comment: @MartinSmith — Because it is a URL in an HTML document not a URL in a text document.

Comment: One Trick Pony: You are right it says that  "& did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)". As I can see it accepts both &#38; and &amp; . Thank you!

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is a value in an HTML attribute, so the `&` character should be HTML encoded, most commonly using the HTML entity `&amp;`:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/home.php?a=2&amp;b=5">example</a>
```

You can also use the HTML entity `&#38;` instead of `&amp;`.